# When you have liquidtitie, metal clad, etc entering your main panel is it completely necessary to have a clamp similar to the bushing type for romex?

Tags: electrical-panel

So the question is essentially, when romex enters the electrical panel, I often see some sort of bushing or clamp holding it in place right before the conductors are stripped from the jacket. So when it comes to metal clad or say liquid tite, do those require the same sort of clamping, or can those just run into the panel throguh a punch out as is?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need some kind of clamp to fasten the conduit to the penetration—conduit can't just be loosely in (or out) of the hole.  NEC 314.17.

Unless your panel or box already has integrated clamps.

Comment: Thank you. So then it sounds like 2  runs of liquid tight were done incorrectly then because I see them entering but nothing clamping them from moving. Anything available that can clamp them without removing the conductors? Or the conductors need to be removed from the breaker and then get a straight termination fitting with the nut?

Comment: Can you see (access) both the inside and outside of the panel wall?  I'm not aware of any conduit bushings that can be installed without threading over top of the conductors.

Comment: No it’s recessed. So can’t access outside without removing drywall. I wasn’t sure if some like half circle existed that could be pushed from the inside into the hole and then snapped in place around the conduit. Because the liquid tight termination will require me to remove the conduit from the hole completely since it has to be placed from the outside.

Comment: What size and number of wires do you have in the conduit? And do you have other runs of liquidtite that do have bushings?

Comment: Just looks like 2 runs both without clamps. 10/3? It’s red, black, green. Liquidtight is 3/4.

Comment: I expect the conduit is required to be terminated or fixed in place so it doesn't shift and potentially allow the wires to be chafed by the sharp panel edge.  Unclear if this would be kosher, but if you're able to push the conduit out of the box, maybe you could use the basic plastic bushings pressed into the hole from inside the panel?  You still might run the risk of the conduit pushing itself back in and dislodging the bushing, though.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Would this be the same for metal clad as well then? It’s like flexible like the liquid right but much harder and well feels like metal. There’s a single run of that as well that appears to not be clamped in place. I’ve been googling trying to find something that can just be used to clamp them in place as is :(. Nothing so far. Maybe I’ll post another question here and see if someone knows. I appreciate all the insight though.

Comment: I don't know offhand, but pretty much any question can be enhanced by providing detailed photographs of the condition...